# storage blob upload command failed after setting AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING

Tags: macos, azure, blob

I'm trying to upload a file to my azure storage. I did

```
$ set AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=**;AccountKey=**
```

but when I did

```
$ azure storage blob upload PATHFILE mycontainer data/book_270.pdf
```

then I got the following error:

> info:    Executing command storage blob upload
> error:   Please set the storage account parameters or one of the following two environment variables to use the storage command.

1. AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
2. AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT and AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY

> info:    Error information has been recorded to /Users/uqtngu83/.azure/azure.err
>
> error:   storage blob upload command failed

But I already set AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING! Please help

Comment: Did you restart your session after you set the Environment Variable?

Comment: Sorry this was a very silly mistake. In Mac, it should be: $ export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="DefaultBlaBlaBla". Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment, you are suppose to run the following on your MAC terminal. (Change Defaultblabla with your Azure Storage Connection String)

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="DefaultBlaBlaBla"
```